# What is the SQL Server equivalent for this Oracle create table command?

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I am scratching my head to convert below Oracle command to SQl Server:

```
--Oracle Create table command--
CREATE TABLE "BPM_EPT"."XXPCS_EPT_DASHB_LOOKUP"
( "LOOKUP_TYPE" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
  "CREATION_DATE" TIMESTAMP(6),
) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE
PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
STORAGE (INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
TABLESPACE "XXPCS_TBS";
```

I need the SQL Server equivalent of this command.

Comment: Why have you [asked this again](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75748464/266304)?

Comment: This question is a bit different. From this question, I want to know the corresponding data types in sql server also apart from the storage related question ago. I need the full query. In the other question, I want specific information about storage only.

Comment: Then please edit the question to make that clear, and maybe take out the clauses you don't want/need answered here.

Comment: Next time I will make a note of it Alex. Thanks for your valuable suggestion.

Comment: Did you try the official documentation?

Comment: check out the documentation for file group: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-files-and-filegroups?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm wrong, but - nonetheless - Oracle code you posted looks as if you copy/pasted it from some GUI tool (such as TOAD or SQL Developer). Although table was - in my opinion - created in much simpler manner, just

```
CREATE TABLE xxpcs_ept_dashb_lookup
  (lookup_type   VARCHAR2(100),
   creation_date TIMESTAMP(6)
  );
```

Oracle - by default - added the rest of the script you see. In most cases, such a `CREATE TABLE` statement is OK because Oracle's defaults are satisfactory. In some (rare?) cases, you do decide to set your own `PCTFREE` or `STORAGE` values, usually if you're designing *warehouse*. You should actually know what you're doing because - if you don't and *blindly* set those values - you'll make things *worse*, not *better*. So yes, you'd rather leave it to defaults.

Therefore, I believe that the same goes for MS SQL Server. If you run

```
CREATE TABLE xxpcs_ept_dashb_lookup (
    lookup_type   VARCHAR(100),
    creation_date DATETIME2(6)
);
```

I'd say that for 99% cases this is just enough to make you up & running.

Comment: Thank you, @Dale. Fixed. The fact is: I don't know MS SQL Server; the whole point of what I wrote is related to *overcomplicating* things while that's unnecessary. Of course, presuming I'm right about it. Maybe the OP really wants to mimic the whole Oracle's script; can't tell.

Answer (score -1):

The equivalent SQL command for the above Oracle command in standard SQL syntax would be:

```
CREATE TABLE BPM_EPT.XXPCS_EPT_DASHB_LOOKUP (
  LOOKUP_TYPE VARCHAR(100),
  CREATION_DATE TIMESTAMP
) 
TABLESPACE XXPCS_TBS
STORAGE (
  INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 
  MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 
  PCTINCREASE 0 
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT 
);
```

Note that some of the options used in the Oracle command, such as "SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE", "NOCOMPRESS", "LOGGING", "PCTFREE", "PCTUSED", "INITRANS", "MAXTRANS", "FREELISTS", "FREELIST GROUPS", "FLASH_CACHE", and "CELL_FLASH_CACHE" are specific to Oracle and not part of standard SQL syntax.

Comment: Running the command saying - Incorrect syntax near 'TABLESPACE'.

Comment: I don't think you want `TIMESTAMP` in SQL Server, I think you want `DATETIME2(6)`

Comment: In fact thats not correct at all... check the documentation.

Comment: @Dale can you give the full command?

Comment: @Arup please check the official documentation